# onlyoffice + docker + nextcloud (автоматизация установки)

Tags: docker, onlyoffice, nextcloud

Есть вопросы по автоматизации установки onlyoffice в docker и связки с nextcloud.

1) Конфигурируем nginx

2) Ставим приложение onlyoffice , связываем с  nextcloud:

```
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings app:install onlyoffice"
 "/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings app:enable onlyoffice"
 "/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice DocumentServerUrl --value=\"https://{{ hostname }}/ds-vpath/\""
 "/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice DocumentServerInternalUrl --value=\"http://127.0.0.1:8888/\""
 "/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice StorageUrl --value=\"https://{{ hostname }}/nextcloud \""
```

3) Запускаем document server в докере: `docker run -i -t -d -p 8888:80 --restart=always onlyoffice/documentserver`

Для того чтобы приложение onlyoffice работало, необходимо зайти в nextcloud -> onlyoffice и нажать сохранить. Либо!
Необходимо очистить поле в БД (что является велосипедом)

```
update oc_appconfig set configvalue='1' where appid='onlyoffice' and configkey='settings_error';
```

Интересует момент, чтобы не делать ручных действий. Такое возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Решить вашу проблему можно добавлением записей в БД через occ. Необходимо добавить следующие записи:

```
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice DocumentServerUrl --value=\"https://<hostname>/ds-vpath/\""
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice DocumentServerInternalUrl --value=\"http://127.0.0.1:8888/\""
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice StorageUrl --value=\"https://<hostname>/nextcloud/\""
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice defFormats --value=\"{\\\"docx\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"xlsx\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"pptx\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"ppsx\\\":\\\"true\\\",\\\"txt\\\":\\\"false\\\",\\\"csv\\\":\\\"false\\\"}\""
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ --no-warnings config:app:set onlyoffice settings_error --value=\"\""
```

Есть момент: при повторном запуске контейнера onlyoffice часто вываливается ошибка при старте службы rabbitmq в контенере - `"/var/run/rabbitmq: Permission denied"`. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно подключить отдельный контейнер с rabbitmq и через переменные env (`RABBITMQ_SERVER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@<image-name>`) указать где его искать, тогда с рестартом контейнера проблемы не будет.